# .NET Library for Stack Overflow API?

Tags: discussion, api

Are there any .NET libraries currently for the Stack Overflow unofficial API? I'm thinking of writing one and posting it here, but I just want to check if there are any already. Thanks!

Comment: dude. i just realized what you were inferring with that comment r.e. name 'soapi'.  I had no idea. i guess great(?) minds think alike. gotta admit, it is the most logical choice. and it rolls off the tongue smoother than SEAPI.

Comment: @code don't remember exactly what comment you're referring to... but the name's great. I'm happy that someone's found a great use for it. :)

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-v1-0-fluent-javascript-wrapper-for-the-stackoverflow-api/1155#1155 - i thought you were remarking on the subtext, now i see you might have been commenting on the coincidence (or the theft of a name, lolz).

Comment: @code ah, yes, the "soapy" comment - when I announced soapidotnet (my ancient library) on meta, someone commented with "sounds like soapy!" and as for that last part, it's no theft - go ahead, use the name! :) I'm going to remove soapidotnet sometime soon anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Umm.... yeah... lolz.

[Soapi.CS : A fully relational fluent .NET Stack Exchange API client library](https://stackapps.com/questions/386/soapi-cs-a-fully-relational-fluent-net-stack-exchange-api-client-library)

Comment: Great library! (I posted this question way before StackApps, so I should probably close this question now...)

Comment: @maxim - hey - the SOAPI OSS ad needs votes - can you bump it an ask your friends to? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/60263#60263

Answer (score 1):

[**there's stacky**](https://stackapps.com/questions/6/stacky-a-net-client-library), which is highly touted on stackapps.