# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising, crowdsourcing

It's time once again to support your favorite open source project through our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. [We are clearing the leader boards to start the second half of 2010 anew](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/free-vote-based-advertising-launches-second-round/).

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220px by 220px**
- Can be hosted anywhere (tinypic, twitpic, your blog); we will mirror the image locally when we serve it.
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150kb

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all

### Ad Scroller

*(by [George Edison](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142114/george-edison))*: I created a nifty little tool you can use to view the ads that have met the criterion already:

[StackAd Scroller](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html)

Comment: **Please Note:** Entries that have appeared as ads in previous periods are not eligible; however, previous entries that did **not** meet the minimum score threshold can be resubmitted.

Comment: ... and not meet the minimum again :P

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: Possibly. Also covers cases where submissions were received later in the cycle.

Comment: If I do a new ad for a project that appeared before, does that work?

Comment: @John Sheehan: Absolutely. We're looking for fresh content. We don't want a do-over of the ads from the last round.

Comment: also No animated PNGs

Comment: If somebody wants an ad done or reworked, I might be able to offer a suggestion - it's always a welcome break from long streaks of  programming. I don't do design professionally anymore so I don't have a portfolio, but I did one of the ads last round http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/31938#31938, suggested some more, and contributed some Stack Overflow Wallpapers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39049/where-can-i-get-stackoverflow-wallpapers/39446#39446

Comment: @Midday: Animated PNG is an oxymoron. (PNG does not support animation. For that, there's MNG.)

Comment: @Robert could you please spend a word on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67272/is-it-possible-to-have-a-stackapps-advertising-sidebar-contest) too :)?

Answer (score 97):

[image: GitSharp - git in C# for Windows/Mono]

Comment: There's a good solution for git on Windows, it's called Mercurial!

Comment: I find msysgit "good enough"; why not fix that first?

Comment: The problem is that Windows doesn't have proper POSIX support, like any decent modern operating system should have. Solution? Install a good POSIX layer for Windows. Cygwin is a good one. Problem: solved. Good luck reimplementing Git in C#, though. It'll never be as fast as Git implemented in C.

Comment: @Dan - Why not?

Comment: The problems with git on windows will not be solved by a complete rewrite in C#.  Not to mention any further updates to git will not patch automatically to Git#.  This project is a waste of time.

Comment: @Dan, @Ken: you missed the point of Git#. It's a port of JGit, its real purpose is to provide a git **API** to .net apps

Comment: @Mauricio: Ok, you may have a point there. Still, the troll-like nature of this ad seems to suggest that they are trying to rewrite msysgit in C#... the ad doesn't say anything about an API for .NET.

Comment: Since recently, there's an automated JGit port: http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2010/10/ngit.html

Comment: I use Git Bash, and it makes things look as nice as when I run in Linux. Anyway for my preferred IDE (MonoDevelop) to integrate with Git a Managed library is needed, and Git# was tried and now NGit (a semiautomated JGit port) is showing better progress.

Comment: Is it native or is it .NET?

Comment: @AndreKR: it's .NET. Note the mention of "C#" on the banner.

Answer (score 93):

[image: node.js]

Answer (score 63):

[image: The R-Project for Statistical Computing]

Comment: I'm confused... doesn't this [violate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/39984#39984) the rule "Entries that have appeared as ads in previous periods are not eligible"?

Comment: When an ad is a simple logo and tagline, I'm not sure how much more variation should be reasonable beyond changing the tagline.

Comment: I can change it if the consensus is that a new tagline is insufficient, but that seemed to meet the requirements, as I read them.

Comment: Should it be 'Statistics for Pirates' instead ?

Comment: The current way could be interpreted as "the word for statistics in the pirate language".  As in, every time a pirate says "Arrrr!", he means, "your bayesian model will never converge on my booty!".  Your way would mean something like "statistical software to be used by pirates".  I think I prefer the original version?

Comment: @Robert: alright, so you mean the same project can be promoted as long as a new image is used? Isn't it likely, then, that we will have the same winners as last time, since people are probably basing their votes on the project rather than the image?

Comment: @eagle: People should vote for the projects they want to see supported. This early on, I'm not seeing the same winners. If it becomes a problem, we'll change the criteria.

Comment: Now I understand it, but the tag line confused me. What do you think of this? How pirates say "statistics"

Comment: Funny but confusing. Definitely deserves more development work - I remember using it for a statistics course and finding R rather confusing to work with (or maybe that was the course's fault)...

Comment: I thought this was a command.

Answer (score 59):

[image: JFugue - Java(TM) API for Music Programming]
<sub>(source: [jfugue.org](http://www.jfugue.org/jfugue_ad.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks! While it's simple on the surface (play music with 1 or 2 lines of code!), there are a lot of additional capabilities that make music programming lots of fun. Some features require more care than I can provide alone (and there's always room for new stuff!).

Comment: sounds like a promising project! I haven't tried it yet, but have you heard of KeyKit by any chance? It is old and butt-ugly, but it is the most powerful-yet-intuitive system I've tried so far of this variety, and I've tried many. You may be able to use that project for some inspiration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keykit

Answer (score 57):

[StackApplet http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet_ad.png](http://launchpad.net/stackapplet)

Comment: Aww... linux only.

Comment: @TheLQ: Well, there has been a little discussion on moving this to Windows as well, but that would require a lot of recoding... but it's a consideration.

Comment: @George Thats understandable, since it directly integrates into the Gnome panel. I like the app and I'm okay with Linux, I just don't use Linux for day to day stuff.

Comment: @TheLQ: Well, I sympathize with you... back when I used Windows, I longed for something like this. It's written in Python, so porting it would simply mean ripping out the Gnome stuff and replacing it with *[whatever Windows uses for creating taskbar toolbar-things]*

Comment: @George exactly -- there's no equivalent on Windows. All you get is that 16×16 icon.

Answer (score 52):

[Free Project Collaboration http://img.skitch.com/20100611-dmtc8c9jhy9jfmcpn7fbkxee72.png](http://teambox.com)

Comment: teambox is pretty cool IMO, I had encountered this before when looking for some other stuff, and it's great that it is fully open source!

Comment: thanks, jeff! i have no rep on meta stack overflow :)

Comment: No idea about the actual project, but I sure like the ad. Gives me will to try it even though I have no need for a collaboration tool :]

Comment: sounds like a promising project!

Comment: FWIW for future readers, Teambox 4 is no longer open source :( http://teambox.com/open-source

Answer (score 49):

[image: RabbitVCS - Git on board]
<sub>(source: [rabbitvcs.org](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/_media/rvcsad.png))</sub>

Comment: RabbitVCS used to be known as NautilusSVN. It's basically a clone of TortoiseSVN for the GNOME desktop. It comprises a set of extensions for Subversion workflow in Nautilus, GEdit and Thunar. We're also working on getting the Git side of things up and running. It's written in Python (PyGTK for the UI).

Comment: @detly I'm afraid it's not clear enough those are progress bars. Still, nice ad!

Comment: @badp - what did you think they were? How could it be clearer?

Comment: @detly - exactly what do those progress bars mean?  Do they refer to the fact that SVN is ~80% supported, but only 20% of git functionality is supported, and even less of the other ones?  Or perhaps it is faster for SVN?  Some enlightenment would be nice, thanks.

Comment: @a_m0d: I agree, this ad has perplexed me (I also upvoted badp's comment). After some pondering, I *think* the progress bars indicate just how integrated RabbitVCS is into various version control systems (I guess that it must have a lot of Subversion integration). Perhaps the lack of progress on integrating Hg, Bzr and (to a lesser extend) Git is to encourage developers to help develop that functionality... </psychologist>

Comment: It's a measure of how much we support that particular VCS. So SVN is mostly covered, with emblems, column attributes, context menus and dialogs for most common SVN commands. Git has emblems and a couple of dialogs, but not many. Bzr and Hg have no support yet.

Comment: @Adam Paynter has it :) I'll leave the ad the way it is for this round, but for the next cycle I might do something a great deal simpler.

Comment: @detly: I believe one source of confusion is that it's not entirely obvious that RabbitVCS *complements* the other version control software. When I saw the ad, I thought that RabbitVCS was an *alternative* to the others. This caused me to think the progress bars were meant to compare something about those other solutions *against* RabbitVCS. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @Adam Paynter - thanks, that actually does make sense :) You know how it is, when you come up with something and it doesn't occur to you that someone could interpret any other way...

Comment: Sorry, @detly, I missed your @-reply. They look like meters (popularity meters? feature meters? coolness meters? usage meters?). It's just confusing at first sight. Try maybe making those `█████ ` style bars into `▊▊▊▊▊` style bars.

Comment: @badp - good idea, I might make the switch in place later.

Comment: Heh, I clicked on this ad just to work out what the progress bars are supposed to mean! The ad should just say "TortoiseSVN client for Nautillus".

Comment: @DougBTX - the point of the ad, though, is to try to attract people to help us get it working for Git, Hg, and Bzr; and under Thunar and Dolphin. Saying "TortoiseSVN for Nautilus" would not really achieve that.

Comment: I just don't get the ad.  It doesn't say anything at all about what the product is about.  The bars are really confusing.

Comment: @detly I agree with @womp. A simple "Current Status" header would have it make much more sense

Answer (score 47):

[image: Hack, Make your own language, Become a Racketeer!]
<sub>(source: [barzilay.org](http://tmp.barzilay.org/racket-ad.png))</sub>

Comment: This is resubmitted per Robert Cartaino's comment saying that it "Also covers cases where submissions were received later in the cycle".  Our entry got in less than two weeks ago, and the fact that ads will expire in a week was not stated in [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/51072).

Answer (score 43):

[image: Might not be a yellow submarine, but still a Project you can live in!]

Comment: sounds like a promising project! a truly modern editor on par with textmate, but cross-platform and scriptable with ruby, could be HUGE.

Comment: It would be great if we can **attach** a compiler(c#, ruby, j#, etc) to the editor; in form of addin(MEF/etc) - and compile in on-the-spot; just a thought...

Comment: @Kman running the ruby directly in the editor is already possible. Ctrl+R , or Plugins -> Execute -> Execute Current Tab as Ruby File

Comment: I love that it looks/feels/works like TextMate and it's cross-platform and OPEN SOURCE. =]

Answer (score 35):

[image: An easy mock framework for .Net.]

Answer (score 31):

[RestSharp - .NET REST Client http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1827/restsharp2.png](http://restsharp.org)

Comment: Great inspiring logo!
I also loved the idea of "Rest Sharp", which is a musical joke...

Comment: I have been making a lot of WCF REST services at work lately, and while it's possible to add both REST and SOAP endpoints to them, for use from client script or server code, respectively, I keep thinking of how I'd rather somehow call the REST service from the server code and get rid of the SOAP endpoint altogether.  Keep it up!

Comment: Nice logo, but the joke is only aimed at an English audience. I think I have a good level of English although it is not my native language, but I did not know that was called a "rest", I thought it was called a "pause". Also, non-musicians may not recognize the rest symbol at all.

Answer (score 28):

[All-in-one installers and virtual appliances for open source server software http://bitrock.com/so-final.png](http://www.bitnami.org)

Answer (score 28):

[image: Yii framework. PHP. Less noise, more signal.]
<sub>(source: [yiiframework.ru](http://yiiframework.ru/files/yii_stack_adv3.png))</sub>

Answer (score 26):

[Join the Gallio/MbUnit Team http://gallio.org/images/GallioAdOnStackOverflow2.png](http://gallio.org)

Comment: Please decrease the space between the 'd' and the '!' characters.

Answer (score 23):

[image: Watir, automated testing that doesn’t hurt]
<sub>(source: [zeljkofilipin.com](http://zeljkofilipin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/watir-so-2-1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: The original image is at http://www.flickr.com/photos/snapr/484776493

Answer (score 23):

[Click to learn more about Refinery CMS http://refinerycms.com/system/images/0000/0896/refinery-cms.png](http://refinerycms.com)

Comment: +1 we could do with more help on Refinery CMS., especially helping with the Rails 3.0 support leading up to the 1.0 release soon

Comment: Agreed, attracting some more experienced rails developers would really help out.

Comment: Should the call to action to be to "help with development"? Or is the purpose of the ad to get people to "try the demo"?

Comment: We feel asking people to contribute to a project they haven't heard of before might be a little bit too much to ask too soon. So we're encouraging people to give the demo a whirl so they get a feel for what it does.

Answer (score 22):

[so++: providing access to the StackOverflow API http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/sopp_ad.png](http://launchpad.net/sopp)

Comment: so++ is a C++ wrapper for the StackOverflow API.

Comment: Why would anyone want to access the StackOverflow API in C++?

Comment: @Kinopiko: [This](http://stackapps.com/questions/39/sowhat-stackoverflow-browser) application may answer your question.

Answer (score 21):

[image: bbsharp - a DOM parsing BBCode implementation written in C#]

Comment: Aha, took my untrained github eyes a bit of searching. I see now thorugh http://github.com/charliesome/bbsharp#readme and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode

Comment: Nice... could it be used to convert BBCode to XAML ?

Comment: @Thomas: Theoretically yes, someone just needs to write the renderer

Answer (score 19):

[image: CakePHP Framework]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Soapi.CS makes using the Stack Exchange API as easy as breathing...]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Invisible Internet Project]
<sub>(source: [geti2p.net](http://www.geti2p.net/_static/images/stackoverflow_ad.png))</sub>

Comment: The name is interesting enough to make me click the link, but then it took 5 clicks before I could figure out what the project was actually trying to do.  The home page could be much more friendly.

Comment: @user: What *is* the project trying to do?

Comment: @george-edison: I2P aims to provide an anonymization layer on top of the existing Internet to access and host services anonymously(neither the service operator knows who the user is and vice-versa) and securly(all services are end-to-end encrypted). The basic principal is the same as Tor's, but I2P is focusing on the internal network aspect(hidden services in Tor-slang), while Tor focuses more on the outproxy aspect(ie. accessing sites on the normal Internet anonymously). Thus I2P and Tor can be seen as companion projects.
@user148238: yeah.. we are working on that ;)

Comment: This idea (i2p) seems to be really on the right track by overlaying the web.  The approach allows the ever-elusive end-to-end encryption withn a delineated userspace and (should allow) anoymous cache-storage manipulation (read freenet, et al).  I'm excited to try out this approach.  Thanks i2p for some inovative coding.

Comment: How does this differ from Tor?

Comment: Both projects were started around the same time. Tor and I2P are similar, but Tor is aimed specifically at providing proxying to view regular websites, while I2P focuses more on creating an 'anonymous web'.

Comment: As much as I like the photo in the ad... I don't really get the connection with the project. Am I missing something? Also, from a pure graphical point of view, the bevel on "needs you" is a bit "cheesy" IMO.

Comment: feels very crowded. also, too many default filters, background patterns and fonts. 'the rest is fine'

Comment: @Guffa I'd guess the dove sitting on a dove prohibition sign signifies that you're able to circumvent prohibitions and censorship using i2p.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It's not a dove, it's a seagull.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Does this project even have a dedicated developer any longer?]

Comment: Just so you know, neither of these images meet the "image requirements" listed above so they will not be served up by the ad module. Once they are resized (and the ad meets the minimum voting criteria) they will be picked up.

Comment: @Robert: Can we get rid of this? It's messing up my [StackAd Scroller](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html) app. (Due to the non-compliance with the guidelines, yet still with 6+ votes.)

Comment: @Goerge & @Robert I think the image shouldn't be served in first place, SO should help to enforce the image size requirements to be served instead of deleting the post altogether. I'll try to make it fit...

Comment: @George @Robert, it does meet the criteria now.  I don't know if for better or for worse.

Comment: Looks to me like some part is missing. Should at least be vertically centered. Also, what does this do? The image does not say anything at all about the project.

Comment: Do is an intelligent launcher tool that makes performing common tasks on your computer simple and efficient. Do not only allows you to search for items in your desktop environment (e.g. applications, contacts, bookmarks, files, music), it also allows you to specify actions to perform on search results (e.g. run, open, email, chat, play).

Comment: Totally confused by this ad, it looks a bit blurry and it also looks like someone forgot to add the point of it in all that lovely whitespace...

Answer (score 14):

[image: Contribute to OpenLieroX]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://openlierox.sourceforge.net/olxcontribute.png))</sub>

Comment: Too long, the background makes no sense (I've never used it before), no catchy phrase, and no logo. Fix that and you'll get my vote

Comment: Yeah, but what is it?

Comment: Liero is a game that is totally worth checking out. That said, this ad doesn't do it a lot of justice.

Comment: Yeah! Just a digging worm cannot call more programmers and players. Put 1 more worm and more 2 players with another skin, more weapons shotting and some explosion on a better level. The text would be in a more aggressive font; the text could be and like that: "OpenLieroX: a game with a lot of explosions for worms and brains". You can add piece of code as watermark in some picture part - like little lua commands.

Comment: Liero is like Classic Worms on 100 crates of steroids :)

Comment: Fix the controls in this game god damnit!! >:(

Comment: This ad looks like a big penis... sorry, but I calls 'em like I sees 'em.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Bookvar open source .NET mind mapping tool]

Comment: The coolest .NET Mind Mapping tool!

Answer (score 11):

[Spray - A PHP/MySQL issue tracker http://users.on.net/~a2h/images/sprayad220.png](http://github.com/a2h/sprayapp)

Comment: No point putting the github URL IMHO, nobody's going to manually copy it from the image, it's barely readable, and it's bad for the heart too :)

Comment: Agreed, take off the URL, or at least move it to the bottom of the image - the heart would look better without it.

Answer (score 10):

[http://www.activestate.com/sites/default/files/images/misc/stack-overflow-code.jpg](http://code.activestate.com/)

Comment: clean. could've worked just as fine without the HRules

Answer (score 9):

[image: NPOI for your Excel needs]

Answer (score 7):

[Help develop on the free open source game creator! http://www.scirra.com/images/scirra_ad.png](http://www.scirra.com/)

Comment: If it really were free, as in free that I can use it. Then you would get my vote.

As of now, it requires me to buy a whole operating system and maybe more. Plus risking my computer to get comprimised by trojans, viruses and more.

Comment: -- Construct itself is completely free for Windows users. Heck, even you can download the source and play with it on your Mac or Linux environment. The cost of OS doesn't change the fact that Construct is free :)

Maybe if there were more programmers interested in Construct, there'd be Linux and Mac ports as well.

Comment: This sounded interesting to me, but when I went to the site, I wasn't able to find any information about exactly why programmers are wanted.  Surely you want contributions of some nature?  I can't help out if I don't know what you want :/

Comment: @Frank, what the devil are you on about?  I can't run any of the other free programs listed here, because, heck, I need to buy a new computer to run linux!

Answer (score 6):

[Open Source Management Solution - ERP http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/254/thumbs/1931078746_b.jpg](http://openerp.com)

Answer (score 6):

[image: 7Basic Compiler]

Comment: I'd remove the "Great!" bit

Comment: One thing tough, you should probably add some roadmap or specification to the project. Right now there is very little info on what the exact goal of the project is.

Comment: @Frank: Well, the goal is to create a platform-neutral compiler that can generate 32 bit ELF and Win32 PE executable files given a 7Basic source file. So far, the project can generate NASM assembly language for Linux.

Comment: Currently there is no GUI support, but it is a far-off goal for the project. Currently the language has variable declarations, arithmetic operations, string operations, assignments, comparisons, conditional statements, loops, and built-in IO functions. Enough for some simple demos :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: TwistLoad Download Manager]

Comment: 1) What does TwistLoad aim to accomplish that most built in browser download managers don't? 2) Saying its cross platform and then hosting on Launchpad is confusing. 3) Like the logo

Comment: @TheLQ: 1) It aims to provide acceleration capabilities eventually, as well as make managing downloads easier. 2) Launchpad is the best place I know for code hosting - regardless of platform. 3) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: survey master]

Comment: video presentation:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-JyCH0OVJQ

Answer (score 2):

[image: Spark - A lightweight yet powerful JavaScript library.]

Comment: Okay just as an overview, it can animate size / opacity. Perform AJAX calls, handle events and edit the content of elements. And there are a few more, there is a list of functions in the wiki: http://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/wiki

Comment: Even if no one wants to contribute to the code, you can contribute by postion issues or improvements. I want to know what I have to do to make it great.

Comment: You can now create plugins for it too (v0.9.0)

Comment: I'd **really** change those fonts...

Answer (score 2):

[image: Spruce - a nice looking TFS web front end]

Comment: Screenshots : http://sprucetfs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/21.png + http://sprucetfs.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/a-redesign/

Answer (score 2):

[image: Contribute to Hotaru CMS]

Answer (score 1):

[image: MindTouch API: For Devs of any Programming Language]

Comment: What does it do? Moreover, I can't even tell from a 10s look at their website what it does. #fail

Answer (score 1):

[image: Contribute to the world's leading open source NAC!]
<sub>(source: [packetfence.org](http://www.packetfence.org/pf-stackoverflow.png))</sub>