# Allow moderators to pin a question in metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, featured-tag

Some "questions" on metas really are announcements which ought to be pinned on top of meta question listsings for wider attention (or at least frequently bumped by Mr. Community).

I'm thinking of really important "questions" like [moderator announcements](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), [feature or test announcements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57017/feedback-wanted-three-day-test-run-of-the-chat), [new FOSS advertisement threads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010) and the like.

Comment: I thought diamond mods could already do announcements?

Comment: @Jon If they can I've never seen any. Unless you are talking about blogs...

Comment: It sounds like you're describing "sticky" posts in forums, which usually annoy me. It would be nice to somehow draw attention to those, without locking them at the top of the question list permanently

Comment: @badp: Diamond mods can post "system messages", which are those little banner things below the questions/tags/users/ links but above anything else. Only one can be active at a time.

Comment: Not exactly pinning a question, but the banner on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is a diamond moderator ability.

Comment: Didn't know that, @mmyers, I thought it was just an admins-only feature. I guess it is `status-declined` then. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, I think this would pollute the questions list.

**Counter suggestion**

Have a ♦-only tag called **announcement** for such questions and have a widget on the home page (similar to the faq one):

[image: Announcement widget]

Comment: this would be really nice. Now if only Jeff would give us announcements when he ads features here on meta :)

Comment: The featured red tag now sort of implements this :)

Comment: interestingly, you totally predicted the feature, and I hadn't even seen this. Well done!

Answer (score 5):

We do have the [featured] moderator tag now on per-site metas.

It is not *currently* used to pin, but it *does* affect the meta house ad on the parent site.