# Pinned questions

Tags: support

Is there a way to pin up a question on the "Questions List"?

I know I can bookmark. Pinning is something different.
I very often use the [TeamViewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) forum where formerly they had *Lithium engine* on the forum (recently changed to Vanilla), and there was a function to pin up your favorite topic to the top of the list.

I have many bookmarked, but there are some which I want to work with, in the next week, so I would like to see them on the top of the list. To find them between all other bookmarked questions is not a good idea.

Comment: There's no such feature; I'd use my browser's bookmarking feature for that.

Comment: This could be implemented with a (user-defined, per user) tagging feature for bookmarks (like for questions) - the bookmarks could be ***filtered on one or more tags***. In the meantime, a workaround is an external text document (or similar). The transfer of information (using the clipboard) to/from can be automated with macro keyboards (and/or other kinds of automation).

Comment: What is *"Lithium engine"* (extremely search engine unfriendly)? Some kind of software? A third-party webiste (like [Disqus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disqus))? A configuration setting?

Comment: Similarly for *Vanilla*. Is it *[Vanilla Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_Forums#Vanilla_Cloud)*?

Comment: ["Lithium Community Software"](https://khoros.com/platform/communities) currently they change name to "Khoros". As to Vanilla it is ["vanillaforums.com"](https://vanillaforums.com/en/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this.  To keep questions concerning your favorite topic at the top of your list, you’ll have to use a tool in your browser.  There is [something similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58986/allow-moderators-to-pin-a-question-in-metas) for SE, but that’s only for moderators.