# Ads page needs to warn about ad blockers

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I'm not entierly sure how, but I was able to view an ad in SO even though I don't remember adding SO to the excluded list in Adthwart in Chrome. Anyway, when clicking the link it brings you to the `rads.stackoverflow.com` domain which is outside of the exclusion list. So then the page shows the intro title and nothing else.

For people who have ad blockers still on, could there be a warning like what (was) in the [FOSS voting question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010) that says "The following ads will not be visible if you have ad blocking software turned on"?

Comment: Is this a joke? This is like telling the police they need to change their policies to accommodate people with radar scanners

Comment: @Micheal: Accommodating is coming up with ways around your normal operating. This is simply a warning

Comment: To be fair a adblocker is not a bad thing to have in todays internet. I chose to disable mine here because I had crashes in chrome and these adds do not offend me. But I cannot understand the hate for someone who uses them "in general"

Comment: If you have ad blocking installed, you presumably don't want to view ads.... In that case how did you end up clicking on an ad and finding out where it leads? Maybe this is telling you that you secretly like ads.

Comment: Some people just flip out whenever they see something, anything, about ad-blocking. They'll even call the metaphorical cops about it. Don't sweat it, a lot of people can't read.

Answer (score 8):

Tolerating the use of AdBlock and similar software is one thing, but now you are asking to officially support it and even to provide technical help.

Comment: How on earth is that supporting it?! I'm asking for a warning, nothing more. Warning != support

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what we have here is someone who **wants** to view ads. Or at least be reminded of the content they're unable to view with an adsmasher in gear.

From the velocity of votes so far on this request, it looks like other users are trying to warn you against such deplorable behaviour.

It's like wanting to visit the site with JavaScript turned off. No, that won't do.

Confront yourself and continue to live your life without being subject to ads. Apparently no one else thinks you should assail your eyeballs to such. No matter the cause.

Comment: He wants sites to add special code to help people with adblockers, and yes, I find that incredibly rude. I find the use of adblockers at all incredibly rude, in fact. I don't think websites that are being stripped of ads against their will by people unwilling to use an entirely free service at the cost of a tiny ad they don't even have to *look* at should have to take the time to write code to **help those users**. Kop summarized it nicely -- it's one thing to put up with users that do this, and it's quite another to take the time to actively support subverting ad placement

Comment: It's a whole page of ads, what do you expect? @mic

Comment: I expect ads if I have no adblocker, and a blank page if I do. I don't expect it to detect that I have an adblocker and warn me that I'm not likely to see ads because of it

Comment: @Michael @Random The reason I use an ad blocker is because when your running old hardware, ads that take over your screen tend to lock up your computer, as well as play music or other annoying stuff. I did it out of practicality. If I'm running a more powerful computer, I would disable it, but now I keep it on by default. Don't want your users to block ads on your site? Then do what SO did and keep them simple text. But to get people to do this, you need some kind of notification.