# Show reputation change in Recent Activity even if negative

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Negative daily reputation display?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45476/negative-daily-reputation-display)

It is confusing to not show the reputation change on your Recent Activity page just because it is negative -- for example, due to casting [a large bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010).

If nothing is shown, one is led to believe there was no change *at all*. If today's (or this week's, or even this month's) net result is -68 rep, the reputation tab should instead show "-68".

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the number on the reputation tab in recent activity?

Comment: BTW badp - absolutely [fantastic edit ](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3674004/revisions)... that was actually bugging me too ;)

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: @John, no, it's a feature-request. Read the faq :)

Comment: @radp Then who gets the bounty? :D

Comment: Somebody who replies, @john. Additional considerations, criique, support, jeff explaining why this is status-bydesign...

Comment: @radp So I just need to come up with some considerations or support.... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few cases where you're likely to end up with negative net reputation for an extended period, so I imagine from that perspective it's just not that important.

At the same time though, if you've lost reputation because you put up a bounty, it would be useful to see how close you are to recouping the amount of reputation that you gave up. Currently, it seems that you have to wait until you break even, which, while not a huge issue, is inconsistent.

I can't see any downside to putting a negative number up there when appropriate, something like this:[image: negative rep]

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually call this a bug ("reputation change not being displayed when net change is negative"), not a feature request. But +1 all the same. I have two small suggestions:

First, along the same line of thinking, the system should display a number if there is voting activity but the net score is zero, if this is not already done. (Example: one upvote and five downvotes.) We can retain the not-displaying-a-number behavior for cases where there really is no activity.

Also, perhaps the background color for negative rep should be different than for positive rep? We can't rely solely on color for accessibility reasons, so this would only be a "nice extra" on top of the +/- or ↑/↓ system that would have to be implemented already.