# Reputation Graph - Total Rep during selected period

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph, total-reputation

Everytime I select a period of time on the reputation graph I want to know how much rep I got during that period. Any chance this can be implemented? I like how it shows the rep for each question but I also want to see the total rep from those questions.

EDIT:Would anyone else like to see this??
[image]

Comment: Yes, that would be cool.

Comment: It isn't through the graph on your profile and it has a hard limit of 60 days, but within current functionality you can map out your reputation change over a period of time with your envelope report. Replace the timestamps in the URL (if there aren't any, pick a time period like "this month" to generate the syntax) with your specified period of time; the reputation tab of your report will tell you all the reputation from that period of time [as long as it's a net positive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/show-reputation-change-in-recent-activity-even-if-negative).

Comment: It only works on yourself, though. @Gra

Comment: I'm just saying it should look something like the picture above. Just the total of whats currently selected. Not that hard to implement either.

Comment: This would still be cool, though you could use a new screenshot/mockup.