# Reputation Graph improvement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation-graph

I was interested in finding out how much reputation a user gained during a certain period of time and I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

I believe the reputation graph already provides the visual elements for this feature: on the left corner there's a label with the total amount of reputation (circled in red), which is kind of redudant since the top of this page (which got cropped from the image below) presents regular user info, which already includes the total amount of reputation.

In other words, it seems there are 2 labels in the same page that display the exact same information.

[image]

My suggestion is that the label circled in red be updated to reflect the amount of reputation gained during the period of time selected in the graph bar (red rectangle).

I think it's an interesting feature to have.

Comment: It was for a different graph, but [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68828/reputation-graph-total-rep-during-selected-period?rq=1) is effectively a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

I fully agree with this suggestion.  However, I think that the existing screenshot doesn't do a good job of conveying the problem.  Mostly because it doesn't include freehanded circles.

Here's a screenshot of the full page.  Note the proximity of the label which was cropped from the original screenshot:

> [image]

To illustrate the solution and how it might be useful (not that it's that hard to imagine), I included the following mockup with the rep I earned in this time period when I was very active.

> [image]

You can see that during this 2-month period I earned 3.6k rep, which is interesting considering that I only have 6.1k rep total over the entire 20-month period I've had my account.

Comment: And make it +/- sensitive. So if you gained 3,589 over the time span, it would look like: `+3,589 Reputation (18 Sep '11 to 18 Nov '11)` or something. With the reputation number in green. Likewise it would be red and negative otherwise.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - I assumed that a negative number would simply prepend a `-` sign, in the same way that the bars show "100" for positive rep and "-100" for negative rep.I do like the explicit delineations of the dates, though.

Comment: I'm glad that you and the other 19 users who upvoted the question understood what I meant despite my terrible *MS Paint* skills. Keep it simple.

Comment: @karlphillip - Sorry, that was meant to be a tongue-in-cheek statement.  The real purpose was to display the proximity of the rep numbers.  I don't visit my profile page often, so I didn't really remember what the portion which was cropped from your screenshot looked like.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I understand, nice drawing by the way. Did you got a certification in *MS Paint*? ;D heheh

Comment: @karlphillip - No, this was created with Paint.NET!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time at the moment to do a nice screen capture, but the [Stack Exchange Reputation Graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/93791/mark-hurd?tab=reputation) can be zoomed in and you can get a good idea of the delta over a period.

It is only available for sites where the user's current reputation is 200 or greater though.