# Open Source Ad Image is Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, open-source-advertising

The Teleric Bookvar ad image is broken on Stack Overflow.

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/all

[image: pic of broken add]

Scroll all of the way to the bottom to see the broken one.

It's not broken [in the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/63317#63317).

Comment: I noticed this yesterday.

Comment: @Geor, it has been this way for a while.  Probably a few days before I reported it.

Answer (score 4):

It's still broken as of today.

[image: screenshot]

Interestingly enough, the [image URL trying to load](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/content/imgcache/848DCEC4AA7FF63B3A26D49DDABE52F32DCBAA4F.sflb) is returning a 404 - but if you change the filename extension from `.sflb` to `.png` (or any common image extension) [in the URL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/content/imgcache/848DCEC4AA7FF63B3A26D49DDABE52F32DCBAA4F.png), you get this:

[SO ad http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/reach_devs2.png](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/reach_devs2.png)

instead of the ad image you expect:

[real ad http://www.telerik.com/libraries/labs_projects/bookvar_banner.sflb](http://www.telerik.com/libraries/labs_projects/bookvar_banner.sflb)

Apparently they're watching for broken/non-existent images and replacing them with a generic SO ad (which is a good idea!), but apparently it only works when the URL has a normal file extension.

According to [someone at Telerik](http://blogs.telerik.com/telerikreportingteam/posts/09-04-15/free_whitepaper_understanding_the_what_why_and_how_of_reporting_solutions.aspx), the file extension `.sflb`<sup>1</sup> is a "Sitefinity library file":

> The .sflb extension is a "Sitefinity Library" file. That said, the SLFB should automatically redirect you...

So it looks like whatever process transfers an ad to the SO rads server once it has enough votes wasn't able to retrieve the image from the redirector file, and the default ad isn't showing up because of the weird, non-image file extension.

---

<sup>1</sup> I also learned that SFLB is an acronym for "Short in the Front, Long in the Back", aka the [mullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullet_(haircut)).

Comment: Images are borked. Can you re-upload them?