# Would you support a Stack Apps Advertising - Sidebar contest?

Tags: discussion, stackapps, contest

I would like to propose a contest for promoting [StackApps applications](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [scripts](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script).

**How?**
With the same rules of [Open-source Advertising Sidebar contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010).

**Why?**
Well, quoting Joel and Jeff on [podcast #19](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24218):

> **Spolsky**: It's just really awesome to bump into people that use your
> products...
> **Atwood**: Yeah, it's cool.  It's definitely cool.  And we've talked
> about this before, but it bears
> repeating - it's like - to me, as a
> programmer, the biggest compl[i]ment you
> can get is for people to use your
> stuff, man.  I mean, that's the whole
> reason we do this.

yes, that's the main reason.

#### We want you people to use our stuff

Would you (SOF Inc.) consider to support a Stack Apps Advertising-Sidebar contest here on Meta?

Comment: "We want **you people** to use our stuff" - unintentional appropriation of a bit of american zeitgeist. lolz. +1 for the suggestion because I would like nothing more than to be barraged with bug reports and feature requests now that I actually have a job! ;-)

Comment: Not sure I understand, is it an advert for StackApps.com, or each individual apps adverts going up against each other? Or is it an advert for StackList (or similar)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe contest is not the right term.

Perhaps 'home grown app promotion' would be more appropriate.

Right now there is really no way to let people know that we gots neat stuffs for them to play with.

In home grown I am not implying quality or lack thereof, just the origin, i.e. stackapps community, the closed circuit, redheaded step child of the stack exchange network, the geeks in the supply closet. the the the... you get the point.

WE <strike>DESERVE</strike> *APPRECIATE* RECOGNITION AND AN *NEED* AUDIENCE FOR OUR EFFORTS! 8=)

I would also submit that exposure on stack overflow would let a lot of people who have no idea that we exists know that, well, we exist.

Comment: Bang on - we've put our heart and soul into designing these apps. A bit of promotion never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 6):

I'd certainly like this. Six to Eight (sixtoeightapp.com), whilst not full open source (though large parts are), is still a costless and ad-free product and as such has no advertising budget. Ensuring users know about it is an on-going problem, despite it placing on the podium on the Stack Apps API contest.

Answer (score 5):

Seconded.  Maybe it'll give me a reason to dust off my StackTop code and make an update

Answer (score 2):

I think that we don't even need to participate in the open source contest, if an app is mature enough just publish it. there aren't that many apps and there is enough room for everybody.
This is like Twitter who publish all the "eco-systems" services around it in its main page.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly put your app in as a community promotion ad:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads

Comment: Mmmm..imho StackApps applications are not properly open-sources projects searching for collaboration/cooperation; I see them as solo projects that don't fit well into the Community-ads, if I've understood correctly the rationale behind it. Anyway this question was asked before the StackApps application gallery restyling when the Apps were buried among bug fixes and feature-requests; the app visibility is now much improved, however it would be cool to see some SE apps banner displayed on the sidebar like you are doing for the interesting questions in the future.