# Promoting the use of StackApps for instant notifications of Stack activity

Tags: feature-request

I asked the same seven months ago at [Meta WPSE](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1132/12615).
*But, nowadays, I know it belongs in the **Mothership***.

[image: mothership]

I've [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bpromote%20%2bstackapps) for the topic again and only found one remotely connected:
***[Would you support a Stack Apps Advertising - Sidebar contest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67272/185667)***

And the "big one" (and all linked in it) that focus on Instant Emails (cited in my original Q):
***[Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14555/185667)***

If you allow me, I'll quote it in full, as *I pretty much feel the same* as when I first asked it:

> Having the [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/q/3081/10590) installed, sometimes I reply in almost real
>   time to comments made in Q&A.   And feel it's a pity the other party
>   haven't got an instant notification, so the problem gets solved while
>   we have our hands at it.
>
> My research here in the Meta shows this two main threads about the
>   issue, and they involve email notifications:
>
> - [Problem WordPress StackExchange Email Notifications](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292)
> - [No email notices on comments etc.](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/456)
>
> In the first, @tnorthcutt points to this StackOverflow Meta question:
>
> - [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14555/185667)
>
> And there, @JeffAtwood makes a comment about the use of the
>   [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) for this kind of instant notification.
>
> Which brings me to my point: shouldn't **all those** Notification Apps
>   and Extensions be promoted so new users (and maybe not so new) can get
>   a better interaction with the whole Stack?
>
> I really think that, at least, a new item in the FAQ would be
>   welcomed: *How do (can?) I receive notifications for Q, A and
>   C(omments)?*.

Comment: +1, though I think that StackApps should be promoted in general, and not just for instant notification apps.

Comment: @Benjol, I'd like to focus this on the *Instant Notification* aspect, but **yes**, having the [Shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) closed, maybe the "Stack App Store" would make a good sister to "Careers" => this was a random thought, of course ;)

Comment: Side note, here's my comment notification recipe at [IfTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/62959)