# Is asking for people to join an open source project allowed?

Tags: support, advertising, open-source

Currently I am planning an open source project using `VOIP over HTML5 websockets` which uses `HTML Media Capture` which only released 2 months ago.

My question is, am I allowed to ask people who are interested to join this project on StackOverflow, or should I used a paid option at careers.stackoverflow?

Info about the project on StackOverflow: [implementing voip using html5 websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220672/implementing-voip-using-html5-websockets).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that you're trying to solicit support for a Open Source project, I think you should consider this instead: [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53346/150097).

Create a simple advert for your project, then wait for it to get shown on SO as an advert. Other than that, I don't think there are any good option for getting help with your project.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not a technical question with correct answers, so it's not an SO question. If you want to pay for a Careers listing, I suppose that's fine, but I suspect there are better ways to go about recruitment.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider *any* type of solicitation (whether for volunteers, open source, employment, contributions, etc) as off-topic and should be flagged as spam.

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70535/is-asking-for-people-to-join-an-open-source-project-allowed/70536#70536)'s and [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70535/is-asking-for-people-to-join-an-open-source-project-allowed/70537#70537)'s answer provides reasonable alternatives to accomplish your task.